# Serializing an ArrayList in java

Tags: java, serialization, arraylist, deserialization

This is my first experience with serialization.  I have my data in an arraylist.  When I deserialize it, the arraylist is empty and I can't figure out why.  The arraylist contains only two objects (but in the future could hold more) of class Account.  The Account class is serializable as I beleive is the case with ArrayList objects.  Here is my code:

```
public class BankDatabase implements Serializable
{
   public ArrayList<Account> accounts;
   private static ObjectOutputStream output;
   private static ObjectInputStream input;

   public BankDatabase()
   {
      accounts = new ArrayList();
      File database = new File("database.ser");
      if(!database.exists())
  {          
          Account testAccount[] = new Account[2];
          testAccount[0] = new Account(12345, 54321, 1000.0, 1200.0);
          testAccount[1] = new Account(98765, 56789, 200.0, 200.0);  
          accounts.add(0, testAccount[0]);
          accounts.add(1, testAccount[1]);
      }
      else
          loadDatabase();
   } 

   public static void openIn()
   {
       try
       {   
           input = new ObjectInputStream(Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("database.ser")));
       }
       catch (IOException ioException)
       {
           System.err.println("Could not open file.  Closing Program.");
           System.exit(1);
       }
   }

   public static void openOut()
   {
       try
       {   
           output = new ObjectOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get("database.ser")));
       }
       catch (IOException ioException)
       {
           System.err.println("Could not open file.  Closing Program.");
           System.exit(1);
       }
   }

   public void readData()
   {
       try
       {       
           while(true)
           {
               accounts.add((Account) input.readObject());
           }
       }
       catch (EOFException endOfFileException)
       {
           System.out.printf("No More Records%n");
       }
       catch (ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException)
       {
           System.err.println("Invalid object type.");
       }
       catch (IOException ioException)
       {
           System.err.println("Could not read file.");
       }
   }

   public void saveData()
   {       
       try
       {
           for(Account currentAccount : accounts)               
           {
               output.writeObject(currentAccount);
           }
       }
       catch (IOException ioException)
       {
           System.err.println("Error writing to file.  Terminating");
       }
   }

   public void closeOut()
   {
       try
       {
           if (output != null)
               output.close();
       }
       catch (IOException ioException)
       {
           System.err.println("Error closing file.  Terminating.");
           System.exit(1);
       }
   }

   public void closeIn()
   {
       try
       {
           if (input != null)
               input.close();
       }
       catch (IOException ioException)
       {
           System.err.println("Error closing file.  Terminating.");
           System.exit(1);
       }
   }

   public void loadDatabase()
   {
       openIn();
       readData();
       closeIn();
   }

   public void updateDatabase()
   {
       openOut();
       saveData();
       closeOut();
   }
} 

public class Account implements Serializable 
{
   public int accountNumber; 
   public int pin; 
   public double availableBalance; 
   public double totalBalance; 

   public Account(int theAccountNumber, int thePIN, 
      double theAvailableBalance, double theTotalBalance)
   {
      accountNumber = theAccountNumber;
      pin = thePIN;
      availableBalance = theAvailableBalance;
      totalBalance = theTotalBalance;
   }
```

Comment: `updateDatabase()` is never called.

Comment: Dont open the file for reading and writing at the same time.

Comment: @Robby This isn't the entire code.  It was too much to include it all.  I have classes called Deposit and Withdrawal which call updateDatabase().

Comment: @eckes  code edited but still having same issue.  Also realized I wasn't closing the input stream.

Comment: Looks ok now, besides you are not calling to update/save methods. How big is the file after the first save? Make sure you do not use an older one which might be broken from older tries.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList is Serializable, do `objectOuput.writeObject(list)` to save it and `List list = (List)objectInputStream.readObject()` to read back